# Is it possible to make jenkins container use a maven container for building applications instead of having to use the installer?

Tags: maven, docker, jenkins

I'd like jenkins to use a maven container I made, but I only can find the options to install maven inside the jenkins container, which is not what I want, is it possible for jenkins container to use another maven container?

Comment: And also, make it use a jdk container, and so on?

Answer (score 0):

Here post have a answer(https://jenkins.io/doc/tutorials/build-a-java-app-with-maven/)
below pipline will let jenkins to use a maven image to run maven container and build project.

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'maven:3-alpine' 
            args '-v /root/.m2:/root/.m2' 
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') { 
            steps {
                sh 'mvn -B -DskipTests clean package' 
            }
        }
    }
}
```